# Try-Catch option does not run in Java

Tags: java, parsing, error-handling, try-catch, parseint

I am trying to write a Decimal & Binary converter in Java. I am trying to use try & catch option for error handling. Such as, if any one input "a" as binary number, it will print "Wrong Input". I have used parse and try-catch for this function. But it is not working. I am trying to find out the problem, but I am failed to find it. Could anyone help me in this code? When I write "1" for binary to decimal conversion, it goes to the end of the code.
 The whole code is here:

```
package binary.with.decimal;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RiaJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int binaryp = 0;
        int n;
        int base = 2;
        int result = 0;
        int multiplier = 1;

        System.out.println("1.Binary to Decimal \n 2.Decimal to Binary");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Option Number:");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        switch (n) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Input Binary Number:");

            String binary = scan.nextLine();
            scan.close();
            try {
                binaryp = Integer.parseInt(binary);
            }

            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Input!!!");
            }

            while (binaryp > 0) {
                int residue = binaryp % base;
                binaryp = binaryp / base;
                result = result + residue * multiplier;
                multiplier = multiplier * 10;
            }
            System.out.println("Decimal....." + result);

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Input Decimal Number:");
            int decimal = scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();

            while (decimal > 0) {
                int residue = decimal % base;
                decimal = decimal / base;
                result = result + residue * multiplier;
                multiplier = multiplier * 10;
            }
            System.out.println("Binary....." + result);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("you have selected wrong option number");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Integer.parseInt(String string, int radix) is not an option?`

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What is the current behaviour? Can you give an concrete example?

Comment: When I input 1, the expected result is: "Input Binary Number:". Then if I input a number, it will convert that to decimal. But whenever I enter 1, it shows me following lines (in Eclipse):
Enter 1 for Decimal to Binary Conversion
Enter 2 for Binary to Decimal Conversion
1
Enter a positive integer: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at MyProject.main(MyProject.java:20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scan.nextLine()` should be `scan.next()`

`nextLine()` doesn't wait for user input, but reads the remaining buffer until the next end of line.

Comment: Thank you so much..... The program is working now. Can you please explain a little bit more the difference between "scan.nextLine" and "scan.next"?

Comment: @MuminurRahman to be honest, I'm not sure why it works this way.